# bash: read line and keep spaces

Tags: bash, space

I am trying to read lines from a file containing multiple lines. I want to identify lines that contain only spaces.
By definition, an empty line is empty and does not contain anything (including spaces).
I want to detect lines that seems to be empty but they are not (lines that contain spaces only)

```
    while read line; do
        if [[ `echo "$line" | wc -w` == 0 && `echo "$line" | wc -c` > 1 ]];
        then
             echo "Fake empty line detected"
        fi
    done < "$1"
```

But because read ignores spaces in the start and in the end of a string my code isn't working.

an example of a file

```
hi
 hi
(empty line, no spaces or any other char)
hi
  (two spaces)
hey
```

Please help me to fix the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable word splitting by clearing the value of [IFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) (the internal field separator):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
....
done < "$1"
```

The `-r` isn't strictly necessary, but it is good practice.

---

Also, a simpler way to check the value of `line` (I assume you're looking for a line with nothing but whitespace):

```
if [[ $line =~ ^$ ]]; then
    echo "Fake empty line detected"
fi
```

Comment: You don't need a regex to check whether line is empty. `[[ -z $line ]]` will happily do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Following your code, it can be improved.

```
while read line; do
        if [ -z "$line" ]
        then
             echo "Fake empty line detected"
        fi
done < "$1"
```

The test `-z` checks if `$line` is empty.

Output:

```
Fake empty line detected
Fake empty line detected
```