# How do I keep empty lines while reading a command into a bash array?

Tags: bash

I'm using bash to create a script outputting a set of values (one per line), then run it, and then put the output into an array. I want to retain the empty lines as empty array elements, because an empty value is still a value and it's the only way to match up to the list of values I was expecting back.

So for the following bash code:

```
> IFS=$'\n'
> foo=( $(echo 'foo bar'; echo; echo; echo baz) )
> echo ${#foo[@]}
2
```

I expected to see 4 output, because there were four lines of output. Instead only the lines with something on them are included, so there are only two values in the array.

The following alternatives didn't help:

```
> foo=( `echo 'foo bar'; echo; echo; echo baz` )
> echo ${#foo[@]}
2
> foo=( "$(echo 'foo bar'; echo; echo; echo baz)" )
> echo ${#foo[@]}
1
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776911/bash-read-line-and-keep-spaces help?

Comment: What version of `bash`?

Comment: I'm working on RHEL 6, so Bash 4.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later,

```
readarray -t foo < <(echo 'foo bar'; echo; echo; echo baz)
```

In earlier versions, I'd recommend a more piecemeal approach:

```
foo=()
while IFS= read -r; do
    foo+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(echo 'foo bar'; echo; echo; echo baz)
```

Comment: If *I* had a nickel for every time I forgot to use `read -r` *cough* hint *cough*... :-)

Comment: @chepner, is `$REPLY` a variable invoked by read automatically in cases where I do not specify a variable by myself? I would have done it like `while read line; do`...

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth `read -r` is a more intentional oversight on my part :) but yes, I probably should include it.

Comment: @Ube Yes, `REPLY` is the default if you don't pass a name to `read`.

Comment: @chepner That is a good trick to know. :) Are there more situations where we get auto generated vars? Where could I read about that topic? E.g. the read man page does not seem to cover it.

Comment: From `help read`: 'If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY
    variable.' Off the top of my head, `BASH_REMATCH` and `PIPE_STATUS` are two arrays automatically populated under various circumstances, although neither is a default for a user-configurable option.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any advice on how to get the return value from the command? PIPESTATUS and $? both just have the rc from readarray.

Comment: Add the exit status to the last element of the array by modifying the process substitution: `... < <( ... ; echo $? )` (I assume the series of echoes is a placeholder for a single command that produces multiple lines of output). Then `cmd_status=${foo[${#foo[@]}]}`

Comment: You're right, that's what I'm doing. That should work, thanks!