# how to avoid read command in shell script to avoid trimming spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
filename="makebacio.sh"
while read line
do
echo $line >> temp.sh
done < "$filename"
```

I am trying this to copy the content of one file to copy to another file but in new file all the whitespaces are trimmed from begining are trimmed.

I want to copy exactly same as of source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an empty `IFS` and quote the printing:

```
filename="makebacio.sh"
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line" >> temp.sh
done < "$filename"
```

This will preserve all the whitespaces as in source file.

Comment: Have a look at my [purposed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20776911/1765658) Prefer to use `IFS= read line` in order to preserve IFS outside of read command.

Comment: Ok. upated answer. thanks.

Comment: Please, as there is already a lot of same answer on SO, drop them and vote to close this question...

Comment: I won't delete your answer, but I dislike to see: enter `bash read space` into search field, SO will offert **571 results**. I think **you** could *vote to close this question* and once close, *delete your own post*...

Comment: *"I have stopped closing months ago and have no intention of doing it again"* - why? That doesn't seem very helpful. @F.Hauri has [opened a Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290816/3001761) as suggested, it might be nice to hear your opinion on it.

Comment: @BlueMoon sorry, that should have read *"...doesn't seem terribly helpful **to me**"*. *"people can't demand what others should do as long as no one violates the guidelines"* - true, and I wasn't trying to, but those guidelines are developed and evolve through discussions like this one (as you put it, we *"get the consensus of the community and make it a rule"*!) I see that you have now shared your position - thank you.

Comment: @BlueMoon In this case, though, you didn't have to go looking (which I agree can sometimes be a pain - I have answered questions myself rather than find the duplicate I'm sure exists somewhere); you were handed a duplicate on a platter, which you apparently read, and *still* didn't see fit to VTC (I don't think you should have deleted the answer either way - having answers on dupe-marked questions is fine with me), That behaviour I'll admit I don't really understand, although as you say it is within the current site guidelines.